# getting a entity framework query to work on a production environment proving impossible to debug

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an application that is running perfectly "on my machine", but when deploying to production the site works however I am having an issue with 1 entity framework piece of code.

My environment is a win8.1 machine running vs2013rc
The Production environment is a server running 2008r2
Both are running sql2012.

To try troubleshooting I have copied the database from production into my local development environment. I have tried setting up IIS on my local machine and it works

> EX MESSAGE

Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

```
>STACK TRACE
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemConventionAssemblyLoader.LoadTypesFromAssembly()
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemAssemblyLoader.Load()
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.AssemblyCache.LoadAssembly(Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, ObjectItemLoadingSessionData loadingData)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.AssemblyCache.LoadAssembly(Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, KnownAssembliesSet knownAssemblies, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, Action`1 logLoadMessage, Object& loaderCookie, Dictionary`2& typesInLoading, List`1& errors)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemCollection.LoadAssemblyFromCache(ObjectItemCollection objectItemCollection, Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, Action`1 logLoadMessage)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemCollection.ExplicitLoadFromAssembly(Assembly assembly, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, Action`1 logLoadMessage)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.ExplicitLoadFromAssembly(Assembly assembly, ObjectItemCollection collection, Action`1 logLoadMessage)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.TryUpdateEntitySetMappingsForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
   at WebApplication.Areas.Config.Repository.ConfigRepository.InsertUpdateConfiguration(ConfigurationModel model)
```

My code is nothing special

```
public void InsertUpdateConfiguration(ConfigurationModel model)
{
    try
    {
        using (var db = new Entities())
        {
            LogMessage("InsertUpdate - "+model.StoreName);
            if (model == null)
            {
                LogMessage("model is null????????");
            }
            else
            {
                LogMessage("model is good - "+model.BusinessId);
            }
            var checkIfAdded = db.Configurations.SingleOrDefault(s => s.BusinessId == model.BusinessId);
            LogMessage("checkif added complete");
            //  LogMessage("checkedifadded"+checkIfAdded.BusinessId);
            if (checkIfAdded == null)
            {
                LogMessage("checkifadded = null");
                var config = new Configuration()
                {
               ....
                };
                db.VendConfigurations.Add(config);                   
            }
            else
            {
                LogMessage("checkifadded != null");

            }
            LogMessage("saving vend config");
            db.SaveChanges();
            LogMessage("Saved config");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogMessage("booooooo "+ex.Message);
        LogError(ex);
    }
}
```

The code is failing at line

```
var checkIfAdded = db.Configurations.SingleOrDefault(s => s.BusinessId == model.BusinessId);
```

As the next line of logging isn't called.

Comment: Aggghhh the Copy to local setting....again!

Comment: Context.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine

Comment: What does the `LoaderExceptions` property contain?